# Is it possible to use a pseudo-element (eg. ":before") in an inline style attribute?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="What I need to put inside this tag?"></div>
```

Is it possible to do this in `style` tag in html?

```
div::before { 
    content: "Read this: ";
}
```

How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **you can't**.

Asked and answered here: [Using CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements with inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141374/using-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-inline-css)