# Custom ol tag in css

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make custom ol in html with inline css..
I want it to be in this format

> (1) text1
>
> (2) text2
>
> (3) text 3

what I thinking to do is

```
<ol style="counter-increment:section; content:(counter(section));">
<li>text1 </li>
<li>text2 </li>
<li>text3 </li>
</ol>
```

but it's not working at all.

Comment: Please do a little bit research before posting a question on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you customize the numbers in an ordered list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list)

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1655/

Answer (score 0):

**No, You can't specify inline styles for pseudo-elements**.

see [Using CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements with inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141374/using-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-inline-css#answer-14141821).

Write as

```html
<style>

ol {
  counter-reset: section1;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: section1;
}

ol li:before {
  content: "(" counter(section1) ") ";
  
}
</style>


<ol>
  <li>text1 </li>
  <li>text2 </li>
  <li>text3 </li>
</ol>
```

OR

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section1;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: section1;
}

ol li:before {
  content: "(" counter(section1) ") ";
  
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>text1 </li>
  <li>text2 </li>
  <li>text3 </li>
</ol>
```

OR

```html
<ol style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>(1) text1 </li>
  <li>(2) text2 </li>
  <li>(3) text3 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why are you looking for inline way? Isn't it better to do that in a separate file?

Comment: because all my project I build in inline way and I don't want to make style tag or another stylesheet.

Comment: You can declare your styles in top of your html page. I do not know how your structure is build, but if my opionion working only with inline styles is a bad practice. 

answer to your question, declare styles at the top of your page.