# How can I define pseudo-element styles inline?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

```
<style>    
::placeholder {
      color: red;
    }
</style>

<input id="date" name="date" placeholder="Please select release date" type="text"/>
```

this is my css. Is there any way to define this inline ?  I mean with style = ""  .

Comment: Very poor question title, for what you are actually asking here. You should point out that this is about a rather “special case”, because it is about applying styles via pseudo classes/elements.

Comment: You can't specify pseudo-selectors inline according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141374/using-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-inline-css/20288572

Answer (score 3):

With CSS variables you can do like below but you need at least to define the style that you can change later:

```css
::placeholder {
  color: var(--c, red); /* The default is red */
}
```

```html
<input id="date" name="date" placeholder="select date" type="text" >
<input id="date" name="date" placeholder="select date" type="text" style="--c:blue" >
```