# :after in attribute style

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

How can I do

```css
.sas:after{
content: "stas";
}
```

```html
<p class="sas"></p>
```

In attribute `<style>`

```html
<p style=":after{content="sas";}">stas</p>
```

Comment: You can’t. Maybe consider `.sas:after{ content: attr(data-after-content); }` in the CSS and `<p class="sas" data-after-content="stas"></p>` in the HTML.

Comment: Duplicate of [Using CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements with inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23362301/4642212).