# Dynamically generate text inside 'content' of a CSS pseudo-class

Tags: php, html, css, reusability, css-content

I want to dynamically generate the text within 'content' of a CSS pseudo class in the proper way. I have filled a **[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4wwc/)** with my example so far. This picture shows better how I want to achieve this:

[image: Example of what I want to achieve]

This is the relevant code (it's in the fiddle also):

[part of] index.php:

```
<div class="checkbutton">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check"/>
  <label for="slideThree"></label>
</div>
```

[part of] style.css:

```css
.checkbutton:before
  {
  content: 'Hombre';
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;

  /* 28 es la altura total */
  font: 12px/28px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: CornflowerBlue;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

I want to be able to reuse that code for two purposes:

1. Dynamically and internally translate it with PHP.
2. Different buttons with similar style.

This means, I want to be able to create a similar button but with different names, or just translate it without extra markup. I have no idea how to do this properly. Here's why:

- The CSS is in a unique .css file, separated from the content. Obviously, this doesn't execute php.
- [It's not possible to have CSS pseudo elements inside inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293280/938236)
- No JavaScript. While this could be achieved with javascript, I prefer to avoid it where possible.

How can I achieve it? I find it odd that I need to use CSS for

Comment: gap between posting question and posting own (long) answer is?

Comment: what do you mean, @Waygood ?

Comment: You constructed your question and posted it, then a few seconds later posted the answer! Did you have it already prepared?

Comment: No, I wrote the answer slowly after the question since it occurred to me while writing it. There's a checkbutton while you are writing a question called "Answer your own question" as suggested in the [official stackoverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) that expands the page and let's you answer it in the same spot. Hope that downvote wasn't yours and for me answering my own question...

Comment: As read in the link I just put, **`it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.`**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as you have the ability to set the content you want as an attribute, you can make use of the `attr()` function to abstract your styles:

http://tinker.io/bda2e

```
.checkbutton:before {
  content: attr(data-checked);
}

<div class="checkbutton" data-checked="Hombre" data-unchecked="Mujer">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check"/>
  <label for="slideThree"></label>
</div>
```

Custom attributes with the prefix of `data-` are a part of HTML5:  [Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)

Comment: For 2 elemts I could do `<div class="checkbutton" data-checked_first="Hombre" data-checked_second="Mujer" data-unchecked="Mujer">`, right?

Answer (score 0):

After writing the question and how much trouble it took me to find a solution, I post it in case someone finds it useful. It's in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YBN6x/)** and the relevant code here:

[part of] index.php:

```
<div class="checkbutton">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" checked />
  <label for="slideThree"></label>
  <!-- Now this can be generated with PHP -->
  <span class = "leftcheck"><?= "Hombre"; ?></span>
  <span class = "rightcheck"><?= "Mujer"; ?></span>
</div>
```

[part of] style.css:

```
.checkbutton .leftcheck
  {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
   width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: CornflowerBlue;
  }
```

Of course, if you have a better method, please write it as an answer.