# How do I inline the :before element when unable to include a CSS/style section?

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I'm looking to style a li element, and would like to modify this CSS property:

```
li:before {
    color: blue; 
}
```

However, I am restricted to only using html, inline, styling. I don't have access to the  section of the document I'm working on.

Is what I am trying to do, doable, and, if so, how?

Comment: Is javascript a possibility?

Comment: You can't simulate selectors using the `style` attribute - the selector is irrelevant, the styles apply to the element that the attribute is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, inline styles take precedence over linked CSS files, so you could do something like this with your li elements:-

```
<li style="color: red;">This is a list item</li>
```

And it would take precedence over either a linked stylesheet, or an internal stylesheet.

If you're wanting to use more complex selectors, you're out of luck unfortunately.

See: [CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

Comment: Except that applies to the whole element and not just the `:before` pseudo-element. That said, pseudo-element styles cannot be expressed in inline style attributes, for the reason stated in Adrian's comment.

Comment: Good point.  In that case, what is being asked isn't possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Comment: @Mat sounds like your comment is the correct answer. Please post so I can accept.

Comment: I've added some text to explain

Answer (score 7):

You can insert a new stylesheet inline with the following HTML:

```
<style>
  li:before { color: red; }
</style>
```

The reason this is the only way to do it is that `:before` is a pseudo-element, meaning that it doesn't actually become part of the DOM. Unfortunately, this means there is no way to style it `inline`, as requested.

As an example:

```
<li style="color: red;">text</li>
```

would style the entire `LI` element, not just it's `:before` pseudo-element, and because the `:before` element has no markup, it can not have it's own `style=` property.

Comment: [`<style>` elements must be in the `<head>` unless they have a `[scoped]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-style-element).

Comment: While Zzz is right, I commonly see <style> placed throughout the page and the styles are applied, especially in framework generated code. I don't condone the practice, and it may not work in the future... but if this HAS to work NOW to solve a business problem, it's a (not great) option.

Comment: @smclark89: yes - my point was not that it is a *good* way to solve the problem, but given the fairly stark restrictions provided by the OP, it seems necessary.

Comment: The `scoped` attribute has been removed from all browser support. Including it in this answer will create more confusion than help.

Comment: Yes, good point - thank you for the reminder to update this answer. I'll do so shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
<style scoped>
    li:before {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Anywhere as a direct child of the `<body>` element and it will apply to the whole page, while also being valid HTML5.