# Convert From CSS To Pure HTML

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, href

Instead of

```
<style> some css code</a>
```

and then using

```
<a href="mylink" class="some class">anchor</a>
```

I want to use something like this:

```
<a href="mylink" style="something">anchor</a>
```

So how would I convert this css in such a form (something):

```
<style>
.twitterbird {
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 160px;
height:160px;
display:block;
background:transparent url('twitterbird.png') center top no-repeat;
}

.twitterbird:hover {
background-image: url('twitterbird_hover.png');
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can't [use pseudo-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles) in inline styles, everything but that is possible in your example.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: you mean i cannot use hover?

Comment: @Zox: Yes, thats right.

Comment: because i cannot post css on some sites i cannot control.

Comment: is there any workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately not with just CSS .. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you aren't linking to an external stylesheet.

Put...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<!--thename of your css file.css-->" />
```

in your `<head>` section.

Take all of your styling and save it in a filename that is linked in the href="" of that line.

Like this...

```
.twitterbird {
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 160px;
height:160px;
display:block;
background:transparent url('twitterbird.png') center top no-repeat;
}

.twitterbird:hover {
background-image: url('twitterbird_hover.png');
}
```

In the .css (cascading style sheet) file you do not use style tags.  You would then use class names and id just as you would if you had your css between  tags at the top of your html/php file.

Comment: Didn't know this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I had a head tag on that 4th line.  In your head section is where you'd should link.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, you could use inline css:

```
<a href="mylink" style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: 160px; height: 160px; display: block; background: transparent url('twitterbird.png') center top no-repeat;">anchor</a>
```

Unfortunately, you won't be able to include the `:hover` bit like others have already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a href="mylink" 
 style="margin-bottom: 10px;width: 160px;height:160px;display:block;background:transparent url('twitterbird.png') center top no-repeat;" 
 onmouseover="this.style.background='url(twitterbird_hover.png)'"       
 onmouseout="this.style.background='url(twitterbird.png)'">anchor</a>
```

please not that this is not the best way to go about it, you shouldn't really use inline styles/javascript

Comment: Cool. but i think i cannot use javascript but it will come in handy for other uses.

Comment: well then its not possible :)