# Are there some way to put css inside html?

Tags: html, css

Are the some way to put css inside html?, I mean for example but selectors like "before:" and "after:"

```
<div id="foto" style="position: relative; margin: 20px auto: with: 500px;heght:200px......">
<img src="imgt/big.jpg" width="500px" height="200px">
</div>
```

And this is the file css

```
#foto{
position: relative;
margin: 20px auto;
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background: #eee;
}
#foto:before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
left: 10px;
bottom: 15px;
width: 50%;
height: 20%;
box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
#foto:after{
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
left: 250px;
bottom: 15px;
width: 50%;
height: 20%;
box-shadow: 0px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
-webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inline style as you have used for the div. But why do you need to do so ? Its always a better practice to keep css in a separate file.

As Zenith said you can't use pseudo-element in inline style. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

Comment: He's already using inline-style CSS in his question. He's asking about :before and :after, and you can't specify pseudo elements inline.

Comment: Oh..I didn't see that. But thats what i said. It is inside html tag means its inside html.

Comment: Yeah, I know in the practice is better separate css and HTML, but I'm trying on this way

Comment: @Kakitori The duplicate I linked to on your question has your answer. You can't specify :before and :after in inline CSS.

Comment: @kakitori You have used css inside html. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: @Vivek yeah I'm trying with css inside html

Comment: @Kakitori Katitori, please **actually read** my comments.

Comment: @zenith Just a typo error.

Answer (score 0):

it is always better to write your code in a separate file.you can use inline style but it becomes difficult to edit or make some changes later.And since you are so eager to use inline style why don`t you just write down your code in head tag.this way you code will be much more cleaner and you can access it in the same page.you have mentioned the inline style in your code.so you already know the answer to your question.