# CSS3 :target with only HTML style

Tags: html, css, tabs, styles

I've got a challenge I'm trying to solve.

I'm trying to create a page that has tabs to switch between content, without using Javascript or inline/external CSS. I'd like to use the :target function but the absolute only way I can use CSS in this instance is through `style=""` from the HTML.

Is it possible to switch between pages (like you'd see with tabs and JavaScript) with only using CSS3 inside HTML style tags for an element?

Literally, I can't even use `<style>`. The only way I can use CSS is via `<div style="">` or via the style of another HTML tag.

I know this sounds ridiculous, but it's a sort of challenge I guess. Just curious if it's possible.

Okay, so the code I'd like to use is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <p style="text-align:center;">CSS3 TABS. <b><i>NO JAVASCRIPT </i></b></p>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li id="One"><a href="#One" id="first">One</a>
                <div>
                    <p>p1</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="Two"><a href="#Two" id="sec">Two</a>
                <div>
                    <p>p2</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="Three"><a href="#Three" id="third">Three</a>
                <div>
                    <p>p3</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<strong>CSS</strong>
li div {
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    left:0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E3E3E3, #FFFFFF 85px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

#tabs li a{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E3E3E3, #FFFFFF 18px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    margin: 0 3px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    display:block;
    top:1px;
}

#One:target div, #Two:target div, #Three:target div{
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

So far, I've converted everything but the `:target` part.

```
<div id="container">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Test</p>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li id="One">
            <a href="#One" id="first"
            style="
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E3E3E3, #FFFFFF 18px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
            border: 1px solid #888888; margin: 0 3px 0 0; padding: 5px 25px; position: relative; z-index:1;
            font-size: 14px; border-radius:10px 10px 0 0; display:block; top:1px;
            ">
            One</a>
                <div style="-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; border: 1px solid #888888;
                float: left; opacity: 0; padding: 0 15px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; width: 250px; left:0;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E3E3E3, #FFFFFF 85px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">
                    <p>Page 1</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="Two">
            <a href="#Two" id="sec"
            style="
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E3E3E3, #FFFFFF 18px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
            border: 1px solid #888888; margin: 0 3px 0 0; padding: 5px 25px; position: relative; z-index:1;
            font-size: 14px; border-radius:10px 10px 0 0; display:block; top:1px;
            ">
            Two</a>
                <div style="-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; border: 1px solid #888888;
                float: left; opacity: 0; padding: 0 15px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; width: 250px; left:0;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E3E3E3, #FFFFFF 85px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">
                    <p>Page 2</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's complicated. For the sake of this request, let's work with it.

Comment: You can't have pseudo CSS classes in the inline style. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Comment: Looks like you are trying to pull this off for an email template? Firstly, you can't have pseudo selectors with inline style.

#2, to switch tabs, you'll need to fire a click-event. Unlike hover, there are no pseudo selectors to target click events with CSS.

I'd be pretty damn impressed, if someone pulls this off with no javascript and just inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

if you using style in html there are only 2 ways either `<style> ... </style>` or `<div style="..."> ... </div>` No other way..

1. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_style
2. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_bodybgstyle