# How do I create Hover effects in HTML without using a CSS page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I know that with CSS you can do for example:

```
p:hover {
    xxx:yyy;
}
```

I wish to do so but in the HTML page without linking the CSS, like so:

```
<p style="xxx">xxxxxxxx</p>
```

but with the hover option.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try JavaScript:

```
<p onmouseover="change(this)" >xxxxx</p>
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function change (element) {
    var style = element.style;
    // Do something with style...
    // Example: style.color = "red";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't think about using JS! thanks for the answer, but do i need an external JS page for this? i need everything in the same page.

Comment: thanks for the answer works like a charm. how can i make the red disappear after removing the mouse?

Comment: You don't need a external JS page, just use the `script` tag.

Comment: You can try `onmouseout` to remove the style.

Comment: Oh but how can I add both the onmouseover and onmouseout on the same text without resolving to a separate JS page?

Comment: I write a demo in jsfiddle, you can take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/bossonchan/LBjap/8/ , and if you wouldn't want to mix js in html, you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bossonchan/avF3s/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can insert directly your CSS inside the html page without linking it:

```
<head>
<style>
    p:hover {
        xxx: yyy;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>xxxxxxxx</p>
</body>
```

[Internal Style Sheet](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to mention that i do have the option to edit the <head> i can only use the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use internal css in your html page as below..

```
<style>
 p:hover{
  //coding...
  }
</style>
```