# Define pseudo-elements before and after inside html?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to define style for pseudo-elements inside html container? 
Something like

```
 <div style=":after{background:red}">
```

The background image will be defined dynamically so I need to put the style in html.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't. Style attribute doesn't allow selectors.

Take a look

[CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/ (W3C Recommendation)

You can, by the way, use tag `<style>...</style>` to add on HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting it through jQuery after generating background.

pseudo-elements should be defined in CSS.