# Inline styles a shadowed element?

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

I want to make a special paper-item's icon to be red, I know I can do it in css file:

```
#my-id::shadow #icon { 
  color: red; 
}
```

But, I prefer do it **inline**, like this:

```
<paper-item id="my-id" icon="xxx" style="::shadow #icon { color:red; }"></paper-item>
```

Unfortunately,

```
style="::shadow #icon { color:red; }"
```

does not work. Anyone know how to inline style a shadowed element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post on Stack Overflow will give you better understanding on CSS/inline Pseudo Classes

[CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

Comment: Sadly, it said IMPOSSIBLE. thank you provide the link.