# How to cancel the blur effect of Html textbox?

Tags: html, css

How to cancel the blur effect of the HTML textbox when focus on it?

```
<input type='text'   style="background-color:#33ccff; color:#AD8C08; border:1px solid  #ffffff; "></input>
```

Comment: What do you mean the "blur" effect? Are you talking about the color around the textbox that you get on focus in some browsers?

Comment: yes the color around the text box. its give the focused look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use CSS on the input element on focus to eliminate that "blur" effect that you're talking about. Take a look at this JSFiddle for an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/qfr8eng1/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="noeffect" value="look at me!"/>
```

CSS:

```
#noeffect
{
    background-color: #33ccff;
    color: #AD8C08;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#noeffect:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: how to use this as inline css?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. See this Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Answer (score 0):

try it......

```css
.onfocus { background-color:#33ccff; color:#AD8C08; border:1px solid #ffffff; }
.onfocus:focus { background:none; }
```

```html
<input type='text' class="onfocus"></input>
```