# Style span element on focus

Tags: html, css

The problem I am having is hard coding the style element focus in a HTML tag.
On the css page it looks something like this:

```
span.select.focus {
    background:rgba(189, 189, 189);
    border-right:solid 8px rgba(170, 194, 31, 0) !important;
}
```

Where is I can hard style the element without the focus

```
<span data-prefix="Shopping cart: " class="select profile" id="wordsPerQuiz" style="background-color: rgb (189,189,189)"> </span>
```

Here is my attempt.

```
  <span data-prefix="Shopping cart: " class="select profile" id="wordsPerQuiz" style="background-color: rgb (189,189,189)" focus="background-color: rgb (189,189,189)"> </span>
```

Comment: Your CSS is failing because there is no class of `focus` applied. did you mean `:focus`?

Comment: Use `span.select :focus` instead of  `span.select.focus`

Comment: You can't call Focus in HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Comment: `background:rgba(189, 189, 189);` needs one more value for opacity  `background:rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.7);`

Comment: The code, as it stands, doesn't allow the span to gain focus in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudoclass `focus` needs to `:` before, not `.`:

```
span.select:focus {
    background:rgb(189, 189, 189);
    border-right:solid 8px rgba(170, 194, 31, 0) !important;
}
```

Element with `span.select.focus` selector is `<span class="select focus">` in HTML.