# Pseudo-class in html

Tags: html, pseudo-class

I currently have something like this in my css file:

```
a:active {
    color: purple;
}

p {
    color: pink;
}
```

and now I want to incorporate that into solely the HTML.

For the p it is easy, I would just have

```
<p style = "color: pink">Foo</p>
```

My question is how do I incorporate the pseudo-classes into the actual html

Comment: You should use normal classes instead of psudo-classes.

Comment: Here is a link that might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The CSS for pseudo-classes can be assigned either with CSS or with JavaScript events (click, mouseover, etc), but not directly with HTML.

However, you could do that with, for example, `onmousedown="func()"`, would and set the styles with `func()`; would be same as setting it via CSS with `:active` pseudo-class).