# How to use ::first-letter in an inline style?

Tags: css, inline, pseudo-class

How do I take the following CSS and convert it to an inline style?  The syntax escapes me.

```
<style>
    p::first-letter {
        font-size: 130%; 
    }
</style>
```

Comment: you can't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Comment: You can't use pseudo classes on the `style=""` attribute

Comment: Something you *can* do is put a `<span>` around the first letter, and style that instead.