# How do you implement :active in JSX?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I implemented `:hover` event in JSX see:

```js
          <div
            tabIndex={0}
            vertical="center"
            horizontal="space-between"
            className={`cell ${header.name}Size ${selectedHeader.name === header.name && styles.focus}`}
            key={index}
            onClick={onSortClickHandler(header.name)}
            onMouseOver={onHoverHandler(index)}
            onMouseLeave={onHoverCancleHandler(index)}
            style={hover.isHover && hover.index === index ? styles.hover : {}}
          > ... </div>
```

I used hover state with onMouseOver, onMouseLeave events.

**Now I want to implement `:active` event in JSX, but I don't know what mouse events to use for :active. Is there are something like `onMouseRelease`?**

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try would event put in function like: `onMouseOver={() => { onHoverHandler(index); }}` and don't forget modify     `onClick` and `onMouseLeave` !

Comment: @Clark are those events for :hover or :active? I asked you what mouse events to use for :active

Comment: Use `onMouseMove`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React pseudo selector inline styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701748/react-pseudo-selector-inline-styling)

Comment: @Nit no it recommends using third party library

Comment: `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` ?