# css pseudo code "li::before" in react inline style

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

I have a React component called "ExplanationLists", I would like to add dynamic inline style into `li` html element with css pseudo code `li::after`, the way I can style the bullet-point with graphic better. For example,

```css
li::before {
    content: dynamic_content;
}
```

However, I couldn't really make it happen. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Below is the code I've written.

```react
class ExplanationLists extends Component{
    populateHtml(){
        // asign lists data into variable "items"
        var items = this.props.items; 

        // loop though items and pass dynamic style into li element
        const html = items.map(function(item){
            var divStyle = {
                display: "list-item",
                listStyleImage: 
                    'url(' +  
                    '/images/icons/batchfield_fotograf_rosenheim_icon_' + 
                    item.icon +
                    '.png' +
                    ')'   
            };  

            // html templating 
            return (
                 <li style={divStyle}>
                   <h3 >{item.title}</h3>
                   <p>{item.desc}</p>
                 </li>
            );
        });

        // return html
        return html;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.populateHtml()}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just simple use `className` at your `li` element, then styling it with normal CSS ?

Comment: Because it's dynamic content, not the same thing every time. Needs to be set via javascript.

Answer (score 21):

In your particular case you can use `data` attributes.

```
li::before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```
render = () => <li data-content={this.props.content}>{this.props.children}</li>
```

Comment: Super cool. 8 Years in web dev and I just knew this. Thanks mate

Comment: Hey @idiglove that is so relatable, I learned that myself 5 minutes before posting that answer , though it took me possibly an hour of investigation

Comment: Note: attr() evaluates to string. You can't evaluate #ffffff or some other colour to hex like background-color: attr(data-content);

Comment: @SatbirKira Yes, only `content` in `::before` and `::after` is now officially supported. More is in the works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible. React `style` attribute use the HTML `style` attribute underlyingly, so it cannot have selectors inside it. Like stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5293299/2180651) about inline style.

> The value of the style attribute must match the syntax of the contents of a CSS declaration block (excluding the delimiting braces), whose formal grammar is given below in the terms and conventions of the CSS core grammar:
>
> ```
> declaration-list
>   : S* declaration? [ ';' S* declaration? ]*
>   ;
> ```

Answer (score 4):

1. `"&::before": { ...react style here }`
2. you must have attribute `` content: `''` ``

example:

```
        content: {
            display: "flex",
            margin: 10,
            "&::before": {
                content: `''`,
                position: 'absolute',
                left: '-50px',
                top: '50px',
                width: '0',
                height: '0',
                border: '50px solid transparent',
                borderTopColor: 'red',
            }
        },
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question doesn't mention `glamorous` library, so your answer is misleading..

Comment: @KarolisŠarapnickis Sorry that I did not notice the library name, I was able to do like above by creating the app with facebook create-react-app command without any other related library as I remember.

Answer (score -4):

React does not have CSS pseudo-elements. The idea is to solve in Javascript way. Put it simply, add a `span` before or after the DOM element. I find it quite nice, more powerful than CSS. Take a look at [a-theme-react](https://github.com/richardzcode/a-theme-react) I built for example

```
const beforeImg = (
    <img
        src={screenshot5}
        style={{
            width: '216px',
            marginTop: '87px',
            marginLeft: '79px',
            height: '393px'
        }}
    />
)

export const FormSection = {
    margin: '0 0 10px',
    color: '#262626',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    border: '1px solid #e6e6e6',
    borderRadius: '1px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '350px',
    display: 'inline-block',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    before: {
        content: beforeImg,
        display: 'inline-block',
        width: '400px',
        height: '560px',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + home_phone + ')',
        backgroundSize: '400px 560px'
    }
}
```

Then in `render` method look for `.before` attribute, render `content` with styles.