# Set selector style in html code dynamically

Tags: css, ejs

I have three buttons. They have an animation when hovered over. I load my file with the ejs render engine. I want to have different animation colors for the three buttons, and set these dynamically when I send the html page.

I tried something like this:

```html
<button class="button button--style" onclick="window.location.href='/location'" style=":after {background: <%= color %>;}">Button 1</button>
```

All the animation is defined throught `button-style`, I also define the after style there:

```css
.button--style::after {
    background: #f00;
}
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot use pseudo-classes, like `:after` in the style attribute (inline styles). [CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

Comment: What you rather should do instead is create additional CSS classes for this purpose and put them on the button when you need them.

Comment: Would use vue.js for something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use classes instead and set your classes in code behind.  As mentioned, you can't use pseudo classes in a style tag;

```
<button class="button button--style" onclick="window.location.href='/location'" class="<%= class1variable %>">Button 1</button>

class1::after {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

class2::after {
    background-color: #BLAH;
}
```