# Add hover effect to react div using inline styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a div which takes the shape of a circle the **css** property to display a circle is taken from the `circle` class. The color of the circular div is taken from the inline styling. Here a function called `Status()` is used where it will return a hex color code. The circle renders with the colors according to the status we pass to the Status function. To achieve the hover effect i added a ':hover' property to the styling object but it doesn't work. Here is the code that i have tried. Any idea on how to achieve this?. i need to add a boarder/glow to the circle on mouse hover.

```
<div
  className="circle"
  style={{
   backgroundColor: Status('new'),
   ':hover': {
     boxShadow: `0px 0px 4px 2px ${Status('complience')}`,
    },
   }}
 />
```

Comment: You can't - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>Try adding `&` before `:hover`</del>

This is not possible with inline styles, you may want to use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` props to get the hover state and use it, for example :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state= {
    hover: false,
  }
  handleMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({ hover: true });
  }
  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({ hover: false });
  }
  render() {
    const { hover } = this.state;
    return(
      <div
        className="circle"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: Status('new'),
          ...(hover && { boxShadow: `0px 0px 4px 2px ${Status('complience')}`}),
        }}
        onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} // Or onMouseOver
        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Alternatives :

- Use a third party styling library (e.g. [Styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components))
- Use classnames / css stylesheets

Comment: I have already done that but it doesn't work. any reason why the hover effect is not working in jsx?

Comment: @TRomesh Ok sorry for that, selectors are not allowed in inline styles. I edited my answer.