# Want to change height width on img:hover in inline CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am working with dynamic template where HTML code generated from Back-end(using typescript as back-end). 
I want to write `inline css` on `hover`. Already written this code but does not work it.

```
style=":hover { height: 72%; width: 117%;}; cursor:pointer; height:70%; width:115%;"
```

> Code Sample:

```
<img class="ImgStyle1" src="{{item.FrontPage}}" id="iCapImg" name="nBookImg{{i}}" (click)="fullScreenImage($event)" alt="{{item.Caption}}" style=":hover { height: 72%; width: 117%;}; cursor:pointer; height:70%; width:115%;">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This will unnecessarily complicate the `html`. I would suggest making a `css` class to handle this.

Comment: It's dynamic template that generated from back-end. So CSS class does not instantly work here.

Comment: In that case, as mentioned in the answer tagged by @SergiuMolnar you should handle this in `typescript`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Comment: It's not duplicate i want solution for image tag.

Comment: hi will you please let me know what you want to do on hover, like you want to show some text on image hover, any way for inline hover css use jQuery or javascript Example : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css/

Comment: (mouseover)="method()" should be used. You can't is the answer.  Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Comment: People are arguing about how to apply the hover, but the real issue here is that you're misusing Angular. You're not supposed to get HTML from the backend and display it with SPAs. If you want to do that, go to something like JEE or PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** thanks to comment of Maryannah

there a problem that [ngStyle] not admit in-line an object

```
<p [ngStyle]="{background-color:red}"> /**ERROR**/
```

A way is using museover mouse out, a variable and [style.propertie], some like

```
<img (mouseover)="mouseOver=true" 
   (mouseout)="mouseOver=false" 
   [style.height]="mouseOver?'72%':'70%'
   [style.width]="mouseOver?'117%':'115%'
   ...
   class="ImgStyle1" 
   src="{{item.FrontPage}}" 
   id="iCapImg" name="nBookImg{{i}}" 
   (click)="fullScreenImage($event)" 
   alt="{{item.Caption}}"
</img>
```

The other the answer of Maryannah

Comment: You can put it inline.

Comment: @Maryannah, can you give me an example? (It's not ironic, really I like know how)

Comment: Sorry, I don't saw your answer ::glups::

Comment: Strange ... Well the code is thin : `<div #ref (hover)="ref.style.width = '100%'" [style.width.%]="50">`

Comment: Just remembered there's no hover hook, so that would instead be `<div #ref (mouseenter)="ref.style.width = '100%'" (mouseleave)="ref.style.width = '50%'" [style.width.%]="50">` (but still inline)

Comment: @Eliseo it's really closed to solve. I am now just facing multiple image over effect on single image hover. Help me please.

Comment: I think that, then the better aproach is using Angular animations, but this has nothing about put inline style

Answer (score 0):

To put it inline (might be ugly but hey, you asked for it)

```
<div #ref (mouseenter)="ref.style.width = '100%'" (mouseleave)="ref.style.width = '50%'" [style.width.%]="50">
```

This simply is

> On hover, programmatically change the style of the view child element