# Inline CSS for :hover states no rendering in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I'm sure I'm making a simple and idiotic error, so please have mercy.

I am trying to write inline CSS for some clojurescript elements and the following code compiles, but the expected hover color does not render.

Does anyone see what is wrong?

```
[:div  
[bp/icon 
{:icon "database" 
:style {:color "#555555" :padding "10px" :background-color "rgb(250, 250, 250)" :hover "rgb(255, 63, 0)"
}}]]
```

EDIT:

I've also tried this approach, also with no success:

````
            [:div {:class "bp3-button-group"}
             [:div  [bp/icon {:icon "database" :style {:color "#555555" :padding "10px" :background-color "rgb(250, 250, 250)" :&:hover {:background-color "#000"}

                                                       }}]

              ]]
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-classes like `:hover` cannot be applied via inline styles. They can only be applied to CSS selectors themselves but since you are not using a named class you can't apply pseudo-classes either.

The typical CSS-in-JS libraries generated a "virtual" classname and instead of applying the actual styles to the element just apply the classname and create a matching CSS selector at runtime.

You will either have to create an external CSS with the styles created manually

```
// some.css
.some-class { ... }
.some-class:hover { ... }

// your.cljs
[:bp/icon {:icon "database" :class "some-class} ...]
```

use some library that does this for you at runtime (eg. `garden`) or immitate the same "hover" behavior by attaching custom JS event handlers for `onmouseenter` `onmouseout` and manipulating actual styles at runtime.

Inline styles are fairly limited in what they can achieve (eg. no media-queries either) so you want to stick with actual CSS for the most part. Either directly or via JS that generates it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed pseudo classes are not supported in inlined CSS: [CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

You can have a separated CSS file generated by `garden` with the full power of pseudo classes, media-queries, etc.

Or, you can look for a clojurescript library inspired from the CSS in JS trend that support your needs, like Herb: http://herb.roosta.sh/#pseudo