# How do you apply pseudo selectors for css using material style props?

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, material-ui

Currently I'm trying to apply a pseudo-selector using the material UI style prop object.
Styles are currently applied with method with the exclusion of the pseudo element.

styles.jsx--

```js
const SBoxMain = {
  display:"inline-block",
  margin:"0px 5px",
  hover: {backgroundColor: "yellow"}
}
```

Component.jsx--

```js
<Box style={SBoxMain} id="Other" onClick={e => filterType("Other")}>
  <Box style={SBoxTile}>
    Other
  </Box>
</Box>
```

While above code does not throw any error, there is no pseudo element logic applied to the HTML. 
How would I implement logic for ::after and :hover respectively?

Comment: You can't target pseudo-selectors using inline styles. You need to use CSS classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293280/1943571

Answer (score 0):

pseudo selects can be used in conjunction with material ui classes.

```
content: {
display: "flex",
"&::before": {
  content: '""',
  boxShadow: "0 0 6px 1px #ccc"
},
```

To add pseudo-selectors to classes,just append "&" to the pseudo selector string.