# Dash: is there a way to make a sidebar with images instead of text?

Tags: python, jupyterdash

For JupyterDash in python, is it possible to create a sidebar that has images inside of it instead of text? Either to just display the images or to be able to click on the images & have that image link to something else.
I haven’t been able to find an example of this online, so wanted to check if this was even possible with Dash.

Here’s the sidebar in question: [Changing boostrap nav-pills styles using dash python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106013/changing-boostrap-nav-pills-styles-using-dash-python)