# How to manage CSS pseudo-classes in Plotly/Dash?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to change the background and color of the text in the drop-down list, but the background changes only in the mainline, and the color of the text on the contrary in the expanded list.
How can I solve this problem?
How do I change the background on hover?
How to correctly register pseudo-classes for Dash, for example, a: hover?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

style = {'background': '#111', 'color': 'blue', 'textAlign': 'center'}
dropdown_style = {'color':'red', 'width': '300px', 'background': '#777'}

upload_div = html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
                id='upload_id',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['a', 'b']],
                value='a',
                style = dropdown_style
                ), 
        html.Div(id='container')])

@app.callback(
    Output('container', 'children'),
    Input('upload_id', 'value')
)
def update_uploads(upload):
    return upload

app.layout = html.Div(id='body', children=upload_div, style=style)
app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [not possible with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293280/9098350), but it possible if you include css files in your dash app. For how to include css in dash apps see the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources).

Now as far as actually changing the background color of an individual option in a dropdown goes. I've looked in the inspector and found each individual select item is a div with a class of `VirtualizedSelectOption`.

So we can target each element that has this class and add the hover styles to it like this:

```
div.VirtualizedSelectOption:hover  {
  background-color: blue;
}
```