# In react style focus inline does not work

Tags: reactjs

```
          <button
            type="submit"
            name="submit"
            color="primary"
            className="test-class"
            style={{
              background: "var(--back-color)",
              borderRadius: "5px",
              color: "var(--text-color)",
              cursor: "pointer",
              padding: "10px",
              border: "none",
              fontSize: "1rem",
              ":focus": {
                outline: "none",
              },
            }}
          >
            LOGIN
          </button>
```

and if I change `":focus"` to `"&:focus"`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: this question answered in this link:
[CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot target the [pseudo-classes](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/) or [pseudo-elements](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/pseudo-element-before-after/) in inline-css.