# how to use pseudo-classes (like after, before) inline in CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-class

i'm writing an email template and was told to use only inline css (because of email providers/servers restrictions), but i need to use a `:before` pseudo-class and not sure how to do so inline. so far the only other way to use it inline is with javascript but unfortunately that's also not an option.

is that even possible?

Comment: just to clarify: by inline i mean that i cannot use a .css file or define classes in the `<head>` section.

Comment: I think the correct answer is: forget it. You won't be able to use `:inline` in an E-Mail template, at least not reliably.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is is possible to create inline pseudo styles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986618/is-is-possible-to-create-inline-pseudo-styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think it is not possible.**

Pseudo-classes are a member of the family of selectors, which don't occur in the attribute.

Using javascript,something like ,,,

```
<a href="#" 
   onmouseover = "this.style.color = 'none'"
   onmouseout  = "this.style.color = 'blue'">Hello</a>
```

This is inline,but not css.

Comment: like i said, unfortunately js is also not an option... :(
thanks though