# Change <a> tag text color of React Component

Tags: reactjs, colors, hyperlink, components

I'm trying to change the text color of a  tag link. But it does not work. I don't understand how the "a:link" and "a:visited" syntax should look in the component class in the "testBoXStyle " var.

The code of the component:

```
class TestBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opac: 0.0,
            wid: 5,
            hei: 5,
            topp: 200,
            leftt: 200
            };

        updateTestBoxState = updateTestBoxState.bind(this);
    }

    render(){
        var testBoXStyle = {
            transition: 'width 0.2s ease-out, height 0.2s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out, transform 0.5s ease-out, left 0.5s ease-out, top 0.5s ease-out',
            width: this.state.wid,
            height: this.state.hei,
            backgroundColor: '#2222FF',
            opacity: this.state.opac,
            boxShadow: "3px 3px 20px #333333",
            borderRadius: 5,
            padding: 10,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: this.state.topp,
            left: this.state.leftt,
            a:'link {color: white)}',
            a:'visited {color: white)}'
        }

        return (
            <div style={testBoXStyle}>
                <h1>Contacts:</h1>
                Some info...
                <br/>Some info...
                <br/>Some info...   
                <br/>Some info...
                <br/>Some info...
                <br/><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inline css [does not support pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986618/is-it-possible-to-create-inline-pseudo-styles) (like `:visited`).
To use pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements you need to use something other than inline styling.

Just importing a css file and using the relevant classes is sometimes enough.

**Using regular style sheet**

```
import React from 'react'
import './myStylesheet.css'

class TestBox extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
        <div class='myDivClass'>
            <a>Some info...</a>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And then you define the `myDivClass` style inside `myStylesheet.css`.

```
.myDivClass a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```

**Using [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)** you would do:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
    a:visited {
        color: white;
    }
`

class TestBox extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
        <StyledDiv>
            <a>Some info...</a>
        </StyledDiv>
        );
    }
}
```

This nesting in the StyledDiv works because styled-components support scss.